How to use conditional ternary operator for mulitple cases javascript?
Hi i am trying to use ternary operator for multiple cases.
below is the code snippet,
const status_color_to_icon_name = {
    white: 'info',
    orange: 'major',
}

const default_icon_name = 'icon1';

<Icon name={status_color_to_icon_name[item.color] ?? default_icon_name} color= 
    {item.color} />

the above works fine. it looks for item name based on item.color if no name found in status_color_to_icon_name based on item.color it returns default_icon_name
now i have other condition if item.color is 'red' then i want to use custom_icon
i have tried below,
const custom_icon ='icon2';


const status_color_to_icon_name = {
    white: 'info',
    orange: 'major',
}

const default_icon_name = 'icon1';

<Icon name={item.color === 'red' ? custom_icon : 
    status_color_to_icon_name[item.color] ?? default_icon_name} color= 
    {item.color} />

but the above doesnt seem correct. could someone help me with this. thanks.
EDIT: fixed the typo for custom_icon_name and also this item.color could be undefined tried like so
<Icon name={(item.color && item.color === 'red')  ? custom_icon : 
    status_color_to_icon_name[item.color] ?? default_icon_name} 
/>

can we rewrite this something better.

custom_icon_name is not really defined in your scope. I guess it is a typo, thus question should be closed .

"but the above doesnt seem correct.", why not? Please share the output, any errors in console? What did you expect, what happend?

I'm still not quite sure what the problem is. What output are you expecting by using ??

i have updated the question in the edit section

I have shared an answer and also additional code snippet for you to see how the result actually will be when using operators.

You can simplify and improve the readability of your code by restructuring the ternary operator and using a fallback for undefined item.color in a more concise way:
const custom_icon = 'icon2';
const status_color_to_icon_name = {
  white: 'info',
  orange: 'major',
};
const default_icon_name = 'icon1';

<Icon 
  name={
    item.color === 'red' 
      ? custom_icon 
      : status_color_to_icon_name[item.color] || default_icon_name
  } 
  color={item.color || 'defaultColor'} 
/>

If we actually try to debug it:


const items = [{
    id: 1,
    color: 'red'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    color: 'blue'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    color: 'white'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    color: 'orange'
  },
  // and etc
];

const custom_icon = 'icon2';
const default_icon_name = 'icon1';

const status_color_to_icon_name = {
  white: 'info',
  orange: 'major',
  blue: 'neutral',
};

items.forEach((item) => {
  const icon_name = item.color === 'red' ?
    custom_icon :
    status_color_to_icon_name[item.color] || default_icon_name;

  console.log(`Item ID: ${item.id}, Color: ${item.color}, Icon: ${icon_name}`);
});



So, the ternary operator: item.color === 'red' ? custom_icon : ... checks if the color is 'red', and if so, logs the custom_icon.
Fallback to default_icon_name: status_color_to_icon_name[item.color] || default_icon_name checks the object for the color, and if the color is not found (e.g., blue or unknown), it defaults to default_icon_name.

Your approach is correct, but there is a small typo in your code.
You defined custom_icon but used custom_icon_name
const customIcon = 'icon2';

const statusColorToIconName = {
    white: 'info',
    orange: 'major',
};
const defaultIconName = 'icon1';

const getIconName = (color) => {
    if (color === 'red') {
        return customIcon;
    }
    return statusColorToIconName[color] || defaultIconName;
};

<Icon name={getIconName(item.color)} color={item.color}/>

